# ¿Por qué element.offsetWidth devuleve 0? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Tengo unos elementos (`this.spanSibling`) con `position: absolute;` y `max-width: 200px;` y es un `HTMLSpanElement`. Quiero saber su `width`.
He probado `this.spanSibling.offsetWidth` y da 0. 
También he probado `let posSibling = this.spanSibling.getBoundingClientRect();` y luego `posSibling.width` y también da 0.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Cómo puedo saber el width de mis elementos?

Answer (score 0):

El ancho de un elemento lo puedes averiguar con clientWidth que devuelve el ancho de un elemento, incluyendo el padding a la izquierda y derecha, pero sin contar el espacio de la barra de desplazamiento (si la hubiera), bordes o márgenes.

Comment: Me sigue dando 0. Creo que es por ser un `span` . He probado a ponerle `display: block;` pero sigue sin funcionar... (sigue dando 0)

Comment: SOLUCIONADO! Estaba agregandole `element.style.display = 'none'` y no cogía el ancho por ello.
Muchas gracias igualmente!

Answer (score 0):

No funcionaba porque tenía agregado en el JS al elemento del que quería saber su width:
`element.style.display = 'none'`
Quitando este display: none, ya funciona.

Comment: Tampoco funciona, ademas de cuando lo ocultas, cuando el elemento pertenece a un carrousel de Bootstrap, una imagen del carrousel por ejemplo.